# Cannot put different photos for different screens in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

I don't even know if this is the right place to ask this, and I know that this is a slightly rudimentary problem. I have been trying to make multiple pictures be the background for multiple screens. Four pictures with a different one on each screen. It was working, but one day it just stopped. I have all pictures in a folder. I am trying the easy way of just right clicking the image and assigning it to a screen, but for some reason it only says "Set for monitor 4" four times. If I select that, all it does is change all of the screens. Is this a bug?

[image: example problem]

Comment: Is 'Background' set to Slideshow?

Comment: No it is set to picture, but I have also tried the slideshow approach.